# Trouble with Access error "you cannot compact the open database" on submission of form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I just started receiving a weird error when submitting a record to my database. It's a data entry form that calls a bunch of  code, and then calls

```
  docmd.runcommand acSaveRecord
  Application.quit
```

at the end. I changed the line `docmd.save` to `docmd.runcommand acSaveRecord` because records were not being saved sometimes. I do not have the application set to compact and repair on close. Why am I getting this message?

The full error is `You cannot compact the open database through vba or a macro`

Comment: As a long shot guess, does replacing `DoCmd.RunCommand acSaveRecord` with `Me.Dirty = False` make any difference?

Comment: @Hansup Yup, that was one of the first things I did. I'm still wondering what causes that error, and I seem to have found it elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here's what I found**

`acSaveRecord` is a member of Access.Constants and is equal to 4.

`acCmdSaveRecord` is a member of Access.AcCommands and is equal to 50.

Essentially, the command I was using is `"DoCmd.RunCommand 4"`.

The value in `Access.AcCommands`that is equal to 4 is `acCmdCompactDatabase`

Therefore, one should use `docmd.runcommand accmdSaveRecord` (or use `form.dirty`)
[This blog post](http://allenbrowne.com/bug-01.html) briefly explains why one should use `form.dirty`.

Weird -- source on the weird behavior is the last post [here](http://forums.aspfree.com/microsoft-access-help-18/help-explicitly-saving-records-72401.html)